# Share variables between bash scripts

Tags: bash

I am trying to make an init.d script to launch my app.
I have two scripts, the first one is the init.d script **myapp** :

```
   #!/bin/bash
   export MYAPP_HOME="/srv/myapp"
   su - myuser -c "exec $COMMAND_LINE"
```

The second is a script to launch myapp.

I want to use the variable MYAPP_HOME in the second script.

Can anybody help me ?

Comment: Your su command can't access the environment of the caller, so your exported variable will not be available. You would need to pass it as a command line argument.

Comment: @MikeWeller, thats simply not true.  `su <username> -c "<command>"` inherits the current environment.  The OP's issue is that they had `-`, specifying a login shell.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that you are creating a login shell by using the `-` argument to `su`, so a new environment is created.  Either don't use a login shell (omit the `-`), pass the variable as a command-line argument, or place the environment variable in one of the start-up files, like `.bash_profile`.